# Wrong submenu positioning in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

This is what I want (and what works in Firefox and IE). The arrow image is positioned correctly on the right side of the menu item:

[image: Submenu arrow positioned correctly in Firefox and IE]

But this is what it looks like in Chrome:

[image: Submenu arrow NOT positioned correctly]

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul class="tabbed">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 (submenu)</a><span></span></li>                       
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>    

<div id="sub-nav" style="display:none;">

    <ul class="tabbed">
        <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sublink 4 </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
ul.tabbed li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul.tabbed {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.tabbed li {
    float: left;
}

ul.tabbed li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
   width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: right;
    background: url("button.gif") no-repeat;
}

ul.tabbed li span.subhover {
    background: url("button-hover.gif") no-repeat; 
    cursor: pointer;
} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/
```

You can see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9NZn/2/).

I noticed that adding an empty img tag does the trick in Chrome, but I don't think is the proper solution.

```
<div id="main-nav">
<ul class="tabbed">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1 (submenu)</a><span></span> <img src="" /> </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

- Move the `<span></span>` inside the `<a>`.
- Drop the `float` from `ul.tabbed li span`.
- Add `display:inline-block` to `ul.tabbed li span` and drop the `height` to 27px.

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ekZEw/

You might have to fiddle with the CSS a little bit more to get the precise visual appearance that you want.

I think moving the span inside the element you want it attached to (the anchor) will yield more reliable results than anything else.

Comment: +1 for useful content changes. I'd also tweak the layout of the menu.

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your code a little, and it works (in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/u9NZn/3/.

Here's a few changes I made:

```
ul.tabbed li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -1.5em;
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_ds3R4wTBTl0/Tanu3Y5PHOI/AAAAAAAAAnU/STdJTpqNJHA/subnav_btn_top.gif") no-repeat;
}

ul.tabbed li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/u9NZn/3/show/

Comment: All there's left to do now, is make that image a sprite, so the browser doesn't have to download it when you hover over it.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm not doing it ;)